# Excel 2016 (64-bit) Last cell located at the very end of sheet, not enough memory to delete / VBA scripts haven't worked

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, memory, vba

would really appreciate if anyone can help me understand what's going on here. The sheet in question goes on for ~15000 rows and ~300 columns and the workbook itself is massive with ~20 sheets that are all linked to each other.

**When I hit CTRL + END, the last cell appears to be in row ~1,000,000 and column XFD - basically the most bottom right corner of the sheet.**

Unfortunately, this file has been maintained for years and it's not feasible to rework the entire thing.

I checked around and tried a bunch of solutions that haven't worked, and I've listed them below:

- It cannot be copied and pasted to a new sheet due to high complexity issues, so that method is a no-go
- Resized the rows and columns and tried to delete them that way
- Used vba script: Activesheet.UsedRange

Anything that required me to highlight a bunch of rows/columns and perform an action has prompted me with a memory error.

I've also made sure to save and reopen the file to check if the last cell has been changed, to no avail. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: "It cannot be copied and pasted to a new sheet due to high complexity issues, so that method is a no-go" -- say instead that that method will be time consuming and tedious, but may be necessary.

Comment: if your VBA script is using a variable to store the row number, and the variable is dimensionsed as an integer, the row number can exceed the maximum number an integer can hold.  change the dimension of the variable from integer to long.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad yes, that would be correct; however, it breaches the physical limits of human capacity given the 15,000 lines over 300 columns...

Comment: @ForwardEd I did not store an integer, I found this solution on another post here where it's just "Sub ResetCell()  ActiveSheet.UsedRange End Sub". Would it be possible for you to clarify or point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: Try saving the file as XLS or ODS, closing then re-opening

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad clever!

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Tentatively, the magnitude of gratitude I have for you has surpassed levels of which are indescribable and have never been experienced by mere mortals. I say tentatively because I'm still working through the file to see if this fix broke any macros. But you, sir, have lifted me from the grave of which I have been thrusted into for the last eight hours. Thank you, kind sir. You are a wonderful human being.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad unfortunately the solution cut off any columns after "IV" so it did not end up working.. however, thanks for the few moments of relief. I'll continue to trudge on and see what I can do. Appreciate your help nonetheless!

Comment: `XLS` is limited to 256 columns. try `ODS` instead. Or split the current file in two. Or see if the missing columns are easy enough to recreate. If they are formulas, it should be easy enough to repopulate them

Comment: Just for the record, did you try Excel's "Open and Repair" option and did it have any effect on the problem? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repairing-a-corrupted-workbook-7abfc44d-e9bf-4896-8899-bd10ef4d61ab